# Sencha Touch Changing/updating the store values

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sencha-touch, store

Hi I have a store with name and values, I want to change/update the values of the store based on the user selection in settings screen.
suppose I have data like this

```
data: [
                    {firstName: 'Tom',value:1},
                    {firstName: 'Ed',value:2},
                    {firstName: 'Jam',value:3},
                    {firstName: 'Aar',value:4},
                    {firstName: 'Dav',value:5},
                    {firstName: 'Mic',value:6}
                ]
```

When user changes settings (I am storing this change of settings in global variable), all values should change to multiples of 2 as below
and update my view with these new values.

```
data: [
                    {firstName: 'Tom',value:2},
                    {firstName: 'Ed',value:4},
                    {firstName: 'Jam',value:6},
                    {firstName: 'Aar',value:8},
                    {firstName: 'Dav',value:10},
                    {firstName: 'Mic',value:12}
                ]
```

I need some idea how to implement this and best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

After change setting, try this

```
var store = Ext.getStore('StoreName');
store.removeAll();
store.add(newData);
```

Comment: Hi..is there a way i can loop into the all values of store and multiply with the values with 2?

Answer (score 0):

each function of store solved my problem

```
 var store = Ext.getStore('StoreName');
    if(settings changed condition){
      store.each(function(record) {
             record.set('value', (record.get('value')* 2));
             record.dirty = true;
            });     
      store.sync();
    }
```